# How to check if a post meta key/value pair already exists for a specific post

Tags: post-meta, meta-query

I want to know if for a given post ID `$post_id`, there is a metadata key and value pair stored that matches a given key `$meta_key` and value `$meta_value` pair.

I am **not** looking for ANY post that matches the condition, which could easily be achieved with:

```
get_posts(array(
    'meta_key' => $meta_key,
    'meta_value' => $meta_value
));
```

But instead, for the given `$post_id`.

There are probably many different ways to do it:

For example with **get_posts()**:

```
get_posts(array(
    'post__in' => array($post_id),
    'meta_key' => $meta_key,
    'meta_value' => $meta_value
));
```

Or **looping through all the post meta** and checking them all.

```
$results = get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, false);
$found = false;
foreach($results as $result){
   if($result == $meta_value){
   $found = true;
   break;
   }
}
```

But I want to know if there is any builtin way to do it in WordPress. And if there is not, what the most efficient one would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs of [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/), you could try

- [relying on the return value](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/#comment-825) of the `get_post_meta()` function, or
- use the [`get_post_custom_keys()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_custom_keys/) function.

N.B. If you're going for the first option, [you could use the object operator `->`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/#comment-1894) to get the meta value from the post, and circumvent having to call `get_post_meta()` yourself. View it on Trac [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7/src/wp-includes/class-wp-post.php#L339).